# Failed to Make Modulo11 Function on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, function, if-statement, while-loop

Create a function CheckModulo11, that checks if a given accountNr is valid number use this function in a check clause in a table with a column that represents an accountNr. (You need to create a table to store the accountNr by adding constrain and try to insert data into the table).

[Detail Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3IMn.png)

**My Code:**

```
create function CheckModulo11(@accountNr int)
returns @tableModulo11 table(
    modulo_nr int,
    number int,
    total int,
    status char(5)
)
as
BEGIN
    Declare @tmpTable table(
        modulo_nr int,
        number int,
        total int,
        status char(5)
    )
    Declare @length int, @counter int = 1, @value int, @total int, @changeNums char(10);
    SET @changeNums = CONVERT(char(10), @accountNr);
    Set @length = LEN(@changeNums);
    while @length > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @value = CONVERT(int,SUBSTRING(@changeNums, @length, 1))
        insert into @tmpTable
        (modulo_nr, number, total, status) values
        (@counter, @value, (@counter * @value), '-');
        SET @total = @total + (@counter * @value);
        SET @length = @length - 1;
        SET @counter = @counter + 1; 
    END
    IF @total % 11 = 0
        insert into @tmpTable (modulo_nr, number, total, status) values ('', '', @total, 'valid');
    ELSE
        insert into @tmpTable (modulo_nr, number, total, status) values ('', '', @total, 'not valid');

insert into @tableModulo11
SELECT * FROM @tmpTable
return
END
GO
select * from dbo.CheckModulo11(972428577);
```

Error Message:

> Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, Line 185 
>   String or binary data would be truncated.
>   The statement has been terminated.

Comment: If you have a question, and an error message, please include that in your **question** as text. Your question is very likely to be ignored if you mandate the users to visit hyperlinks just to understand the problem you're having.

Comment: thank you very much for the advice, I will pay more attention in the future

Answer (score 0):

I found out why it does not work.

Your function is good, you just forgot to initialize the @total variable to 0. Therefore it remain **null** all the way long regardless you incremented it; and it crashes at the end just before exiting the function.

Try to replace the variable declaration line with this one and it will work (i tried it):

```
    Declare @length int, @counter int = 1, @value int, @total int = 0, @changeNums char(10);
```